# SQL join practice

Tags: sql, sql-server

When joining two tables in SQL, and specifying the column which you are going to use in the "ON" clause, which column should I write on the left side?
For example let's say I have two tables A and B.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.somecolumn= B.somecolumn
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON B.somecolumn= A.somecolumn
```

I know it doesn't matter about the DBMS but is there any good practice or ...?

Comment: No rules :) So do whatever you want. My habit is however to list the **A** first.

Comment: I'd say it is more important to **be consistent** with whichever way you choose. At least within the query or procedure.

Comment: I usually write the columns in the same order of the tables in the join. I find it more readable.

Comment: this is a duplicate of a question asked in the last few weeks, which was possibly closed as a duplicate of something else, let me try to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Like all comments said:

There is no technical reason to order this or that way.

Mostly, I use the join columns in the same order as the tables, like you did in your first example.

If the database SQL syntax allows it, though, and we need an equi join, I prefer the USING clause - which works if the join column(s) has (or have) the same name for both tables; then it would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
USING(somecolumn)
```

If you're very lazy (but use with care, and probably rather for ad-hoc than if you want to put the query into production) - play with NATURAL JOIN ....

Happy playing -

Marco the Sane